# Combine 2 lines that when subsequent line match pattern

Tags: python, perl, sed, awk

I am trying to format git log output into a change log in asciidoc format. I have done that using git log --format.  Next, I need to add a bug number that is in a commit message into the subject.

The input below is generated using

```
      git log --reverse --no-merges $1..$2 --format='* %s%n+%n%b' | \
      sed -e '/^Change-Id:.*$/d' | sed -e '/^Signed-off-by:.*$/d'
```

Input Example:

```
      * This is subject without issue number
      +
      There will be multiple lines of text and multiple paragraphs.

      2nd paragraph of the commit message.


      * This is commit with issue number
      +
      There can be multiple lines of comment message. 

      2nd paragraph of the commit message. A line with Bug: issue ### 
      will be the last line. I need to combine the issue ### with 
      the subject line.

      Bug: issue 1234

      * This is commit with issue number in Issue: 1235 format
      +
      There can be multiple lines of comment message. 

      2nd paragraph of the commit message. A line with Issue: ### 
      will be the last line. I need to combine the issue ### with 
      the subject line.

      Issue: 1235
```

Expected Output

```
      * This is subject without issue number
      +
      There will be multiple lines of text and multiple paragraphs.

      2nd paragraph of the commit message.


      * issue 1234 This is commit with issue number
      +
      There can be multiple lines of comment message. 

      2nd paragraph of the commit message. A line with Bug: issue ### 
      will be the last line. I need to combine the issue ### with 
      the subject line.

      * issue 1235 This is commit with issue number in Issue: 1235 format
      +
      There can be multiple lines of comment message. 

      2nd paragraph of the commit message. A line with Issue: ### 
      will be the last line. I need to combine the issue ### with 
      the subject line.
```

I would like to know if this can be done using Awk.  Could you provide the Awk code that can accomplish above?  If not what are other options?  I would like to create a shell script that generate the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '
    $1 == "*" {
        if (entry) {
            print subject
            print entry
            entry = ""
        }
        subject = $0
        next
    }
    $1 == "Bug:" {
        sub(/\*/, "* issue " $NF, subject)
        next
    }
    {entry = entry "\n" $0}
    END {print subject; print entry}
'
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a very nice solution. It works when I pipe the first part into this. However, the script generate extra blank line below each subject line.  Can I add another condition, a bug info could be described in line Issue: ### too.  I just found that case after I posted.

Answer (score 0):

One way using sed supposed that your input example is the content of `infile` (probably needed `GNU sed` because of `\s`. Change it with a literal space if `sed` complains):

```
sed -n '/^\s*bug:/I ! { H ; b }; s/^[^:]*:// ; G ; s/\([^\n]*\)\n\(.*\*\)/\2\1/ ; s/^\n// ; p' infile
```

Output:

```
* This is subject without issue number
+
There will be multiple lines of text and multiple paragraphs.

2nd paragraph of the commit message.


* issue 1234 This is commit with issue number
+
There can be multiple lines of comment message. 

2nd paragraph of the commit message. A line with Bug: issue ### 
will be the last line. I need to combine the issue ### with 
the subject line.
```

Explanation:

```
-n                           # Disable printing.
/^\s*bug:/I ! {              # If line doesn't begin with 'bug' ignoring case.
  H                          # Append line to 'hold space'.
  b                          # Read next line.
}
s/^[^:]*://                  # Line beginning with 'bug': Remove part of line until a colon.
G                            # Get data of 'hold space'.
s/\([^\n]*\)\n\(.*\*\)/\2\1/ # Put bug line just before the commit message.
s/^\n//                      # Remove leading newline.
p                            # Print.
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is amazing thanks for the explanation. This work well but it requires an intermediate file.  I am looking for solution that I can process stream that comes from git log through pipe.

Answer (score 0):

If the whole file is loaded into memory, it's easy to fix:

```
s/^\*((?:(?!^\*).)*)\n^Bug: (issue \d+)\n/* $2$1/msg;

      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      Matches anything but "*" at the start of a line.
```

And this does exactly that:

```
perl -0777pe1's/^\*((?:(?!^\*).)*)\n^Bug: (issue \d+)\n/* $2$1/msg'
```

Comment: I am not familiar with perl. How would I use this line in a script? I was hopeing to do something like git log --reverse --no-merges $1..$2 --format='* %s%n+%n%b' | sed -e '/^Change-Id:.*$/d' | sed -e '/^Signed-off-by:.*$/d' | <extra logic to add Issue to subject> > outputfile

Comment: Simply replace `<extra logic to add Issue to subject>` with the code I provided (`perl -0777pe1's/^\*((?:(?!^\*).)*)\n^Bug: (issue \d+)\n/* $2$1/msg'`). `-p` means "execute the code for each line of input, then print out the (possibly changed) line."